# Z-index absolute positioning background image

Tags: css, background-image, css-position, z-index

I would like to have the `Wrapper-Top` layer on top of the other one. I set `z-index` and `position`, which should be sufficient. Am I missing something? Here is the [website](http://strazci-webu.cz/103/):  Thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is the code I used:

```
<body>
  <div class="Wrapper-Top">
  </div>
  <div class="Wrapper-Middle">
  hjklhjkhkjlhjkl
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.Wrapper-Top {
    min-width: 980px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 179px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background:url(img/header-bg.png)
    repeat-x 50% 0%;
    z-index: 20;
}
.Wrapper-Middle {
    min-width: 980px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #eee;
    top: 160px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Don't post an external link. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are **missing** a position attribute on `.Wrapper-Top`.

[**z-index on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> Initial value: auto
>
> Applies to: **positioned elements**
>
> Inherited: no

When it isn't present, your `z-index:20` in `.Wrapper-Top` is doing nothing.

Comment: Got it...thought that element is positioned when its position is specified(like top and left).

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want..

```
<body>

<div class="Wrapper-Middle">
hjklhjkhkjlhjkl
 </div>
 <div class="Wrapper-Top">
 </div>
```

```
.Wrapper-Top{ min-width: 980px;
 width: 100%;
height: 179px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: url(img/header-bg.png) repeat-x 50% 0%;
z-index: 20;
position: absolute;
 }

.Wrapper-Middle{min-width: 980px;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;  
margin: 0 auto;
background: #eee;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 10;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, havent thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute both of this and give highest z-index value what you want to top of anothe one. like this

```
.Wrapper-Top{top: 0px; left: 0px; position:absolute; z-index: 2; }
.Wrapper-Middle{top: 160px; left: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 1;}
```